# Excel 2007 VBA ActiveX ComboBox adding 424 error

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I'm stuck on adding an ActiveX component. I receive error code 424 while adding an ActiveX ComboBox using VBA in Excel 2007.
I hope someone here will be so kind and help me with it.

```
Sub addComboBx()
   Dim countColl As Double
   Dim cbx_name As String
   Dim objChBx As OLEObject
   Dim comboBx As ComboBox
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim rowNr As Double

   rowNr = 27
   lastRow = 115
   LastRange = "B2: F" & lastRow
   arrayCountry = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range(LastRange).Value

   countColl = countRows(rowNr) 'Sub that counts rows from line X untill the value of checked cell in next row is equal "" (empty string)

   Worksheets("Sheet 2").Cells((rowNr + countColl), 1).EntireRow.Insert

   cbx_name = "Cbx_countries_list_" & (countColl + 1)

   Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet 2").Cells((rowNr + countColl), 3)

   '-> In line below I have Error 424 'Object required'
   With Worksheets("Sheet 2").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=rng.Left, Top:=rng.Top, Width:=rng.Width, Height:=rng.Height)
        With .Object
            For a = LBound(arrayCountry) To UBound(arrayCountry)
                .AddItem arrayCountry(a, 1)
            Next a
        End With
        Set comboBx = .Object
        With comboBx
           .Value = Sheets("Sheet 2").Cbx_countries_list.Value
           .Placement = xlMove
           .PrintObject = True
           .Name = cbx_name
       End With
   End With
End Sub
```

I cannot figure it out, why I have this 424 error. I checked this and other forums and coudn't find a solution.

Here is the line where the error occurs:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet 2").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=rng.Left, Top:=rng.Top, Width:=rng.Width, Height:=rng.Height)
```

I do not know if it might be important. The code above is in separate Module, not in Worksheet as it is called out after a button is clicked

Comment: Have you attempted to debug? On what line does the error occur? Is this the smallest amount of code required to reproduce the error? If not, you should attempt to reduce your code until the error disappears - this tells you the actual reason for its occurrence.

Comment: I am running your code without any errors (after some minor modifications as I do not have `Sheets("Sheet 2").Cbx_countries_list.Value`. Could you please tell us on which line you are getting the error?

Comment: The error shows in line where the OLEObject is created: With Worksheets("Sheet 2").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=rng.Left, Top:=rng.Top, Width:=rng.Width, Height:=rng.Height)

Comment: Copy your code to an empty file and test it yourself. It works without errors. Yet, it will only work the first time. On the second run the `.Name` will fail as it gets replicated and there cannot be two combo boxes on a sheet with the same name. So, the problem must be within your sheet. Hence, we can only guess. Maybe your sheet is protected? Maybe also add a `Debug.Print rng.Address` to the code to verify that a combo box can be created at that location?

Comment: @Ralph, @Grade 'Eh' Bacon I moved the code to new workbook, and commented out everything in the first `With ... End With` bracket. Also, I copied the code for `countRows` function and the `Worksheets("Sheet 1")`
Now I got error 1004 in the same line... looked like problem with defining _Range_ but `Debug.Print rng.Address` gives correct address. Original worksheet is not protected. I will try look into it once again.